# Can I merge these two lists in 1 go

Tags: c#, linq

What I am trying to do,

```
// get members from SharePoint list (can be null)
// get members from database (can be null)
// merge database members with sharepoint list members BUT only database members should have property VIP = true
// by merge I mean if they are not in list then add them to list, if they are in list then just change there property VIP = true
// by default VIP property is false
```

What I have developed so far,

```
List<Member> Members = new List<Member>();
        foreach (SPListItem mItem in GetList(Url).Items)
        {
            Member m = new Member();
            m.ID = mItem.ID;
            m.Name = mItem.Title;
            m.Company = Utilities.ObjectToStringOrEmpty(mItem[companyCol]);
            m.eMail = Utilities.ObjectToStringOrEmpty(mItem[emailCol]);
            m.Comment = Utilities.ObjectToStringOrEmpty(mItem[commentCol]);
            m.Membership = Utilities.ObjectToStringOrEmpty(mItem[msCol]);
            Members.Add(m);
        }

        var cd = new MemberManager().GetMoreMembers(Url + "/");
        var activeMembers = cd.Where(am => am.MembershipStatus == "Active" || am.MembershipStatus == "Pending").ToList();
        if (activeMembers != null || activeMembers.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var am in activeMembers)
            {
                if (!Members.Any(a => a.eMail.ToLowerInvariant() == am.Email.ToLowerInvariant()))
                {
                    Member m = new Member();
                    m.Name = am.FirstName + " " + am.LastName;
                    m.eMail = am.Email;
                    m.IsVip = true;
                    Members.Add(m);
                }
            }
        }

        md.Members = Members.ToArray();
```

**Problem**

Can I use Linq and merge these lists in a single go ? Maybe something like this, pseudo would be

```
var dbMembers = //GetDBMembers that are active or pending

var spMembers = 
              Select all members using `.Cast<SPListItem>()`
              If spMembers has any dbMember (compared by email)
              Then change that spMembers VIP property to true (which is by default false)
              For rest dbMembers that doesn't exists in spMembers, add them with VIP property = true
```

Not sure how can i efficiently put above pseudo code into linq

Comment: Why you dont want use linq? I have some idea how to do it but it is by using Linq.

Comment: @DawidPawłowski sorry for confusion, I do want to use linq, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var allSpMembers = GetSpList(); // get your members as you mentioned before by `.Cast<SPListItem>()`

List<SPListItem> spMembers =
    dbMembers.GroupJoin(allSpMembers, dbM => dbM.Email, spM => spM.Email,
        (dbMember, spMember) => new { dbMember, spMember })
             .SelectMany(x => x.spMember.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, spMember) =>
                 {
                     SPListItem yourSpListItem;

                     if (spMember != null)
                     {
                         yourSpListItem = spMember;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         yourSpListItem = x.dbMember; //make some mapping here to SPListItem model
                     }

                     yourSpListItem.VIP = true;

                     return yourSpListItem;
                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Use the [`Enumerable.Conca`t method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) to concatenate two lists into one.

If you split out the code to create Member objects into two methods, one `MemberFromSpListItem` and one `MemberFromActiveMember` then you will get the following relatively nice code:

```
    var cd = new MemberManager().GetMoreMembers(Url + "/");
    var activeMembers = cd.Where(am => am.MembershipStatus == "Active" || am.MembershipStatus == "Pending").ToList();

    var members = GetList(Url)
                  .Items
                  .Select(MemberFromSpListItem)
                  .Concat(activeMembers.Select(MemberFromActiveMember))
                  .ToList();
```